# AutoFilter Method of Range Class Failed EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge data base with different courses (465) provided for employees.

I am trying to find a way for filtering only 58 courses from those 465 that are needed, instead of having to filter it manually. After investigating, I found out that this works:

```
Sub VerificacionCursos()

Dim Data_sh As Worksheet
Dim Filter_Criteria_sh As Worksheet
Dim Output_sh As Worksheet

Set Data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set Filter_Criteria_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter_Criteria")
Set Output_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

Data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

Data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 9, Array("Seguridad de Manguera de Agua", "Seguridad de Manguera de Aire""Extintores: IntroducciÃ³n", "Procedimientos de bloqueo y etiquetado", "Espacios Confinados: Conceptos BÃ¡sicos", "E-Metrics y Sustentabilidad", "Polipastos y eslingas", "Equipo de protecciÃ³n personal (PPE)", "PreparaciÃ³n para emergencias", "Permisos de Trabajo", "APA - Alto, Piensa y Actua", "Manejo de Residuos", "Food Defense", "PrevenciÃ³n y protecciÃ³n contra incendio", "Resguardos de mÃ¡quinas", "PatÃ³genos sanguÃneos", "Para trabajar seguro con electricidad", "SGA: IntroducciÃ³n", "SGA: Pictogramas y Riesgos", "SGA: Hojas de Datos de Seguridad", "SGA: Etiquetas", "Trabajo en caliente", "PrevenciÃ³n de lesiones de espalda", "Herramientas elÃ©ctricas y de mano", "ErgonomÃa", "COVID-19: informaciÃ³n general", "ProtecciÃ³n Contra CaÃdas", "Tropiezos, Resbalones y CaÃdas", "Espacios Confinados: para los guardas", "GMP del personal de mantenimiento", "QFS Zonas higienicas y codigo de colores", _
"Salmonela: Control en la fabricaciÃ³n de alimentos", "QFS Eventos Adversos", "Listeria: ComprensiÃ³n de los peligros para los alimentos", "QFS Banderas y Politica de Calidad 2021", "EstÃ¡ndares de la seguridad de los alimentos: IntroducciÃ³n y SQF", "Para prevenir la contaminaciÃ³n de los alimentos", "HACCP: DescripciÃ³n general", "QFS Uso de Equipos de Limpiesa", "Limpiar e higienizar: Ambientes secos", "AlÃ©rgenos de alimentos: IntroducciÃ³n", "AlÃ©rgenos de alimentos: Manejo adecuado", "Control de plagas: pesticidas efectivos", "DMS DE CALIDAD", "QFS Limpieza alergÃ©nica", "Higiene Personal: Esenciales", "Lavado de Manos: TÃ©cnicas Efectivas", "Defensa bÃ¡sica de las instalaciones", "CÃ³mo evitar enfermedades alimentarias", _
"EvaluaciÃ³n de Olor de materiales", "QFS Proteccion al producto", "Quejas del consumidor", "ExclusiÃ³n de material extraÃ±o: papel del empleado", "Seguridad de Manguera de Agua", "Seguridad de Manguera de Aire", "Rastreabilidad y retiro de producto", "Acciones correctivas y preventivas", "IdentificaciÃ³n de producto", "Control y llenado de registros", "Limpieza", "Extintores: IntroducciÃ³n"), xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

It is already working, however the moment when I try to add a button to run this command, it give this error message: Run time error "1004" **AutoFilter Method of Range Class failed**. It is weird because if I do not add the button, the macro runs correctly... Does anyone know how to fix it?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJlLo.png

Comment: I just figured out how to solve it.... Thanks!

Comment: Consider sharing your solution for others to use!